# What is this number in the java log file?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a number in the beginning of my log file:

```
[10/17/12 17:44:03:341 CDT] 00000066 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [WC].....
```

I don't know what it is, or if this is enough info for anyone to tell what it is.
My goal is to grab this number in code to be used somewhere.
It's not the thread id, I tried:

```
Thread.currentThread().getId()
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using log4j? or else?

Comment: Can you show a few more (consecutive) lines?

Comment: can you show us your PatternLayout?

Comment: I added more info to the log line

Comment: this appears to be a WebSphere specific thing

Comment: It's the tread id, but the id from the logger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 8 digit number appears to be specific to WebSphere logs. They might correspond to the error codes on this page: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tsminfo/v6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itsm.tshoot.doc%2Fr_pdg_retcodes.html

In which case 00000066 would be a keyfile i/o error.

Or, it could be a line number. That is a rather logical place to put the line number. I searched other similar 8 digit codes and some of them did not correspond to the above error codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4j, you could learn something new about the messages over here - http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html Either just look up  the log message structure of what you use in google.